# Ruby on Rails Updated_at reveals nil class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When I use `favourite.updated_at`, I can see a date. However when I tried to format it `favourite.updated_at.to_formatted_s(:short)` I got the error:
 **undefined method `to_time' for nil:NilClass**

Here is my code:

```
<% @favourites.each do |f| %>
        <%= f.name %>
        <%= f.updated_at.to_formatted_s(:short) %>                    
<% end %>
```

Comment: I would check here http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/Time/to_formatted_s to see if the version of Rails you're using supports this method.

Comment: But I have been using this method fine in other pages

Comment: Okay. Then, is the f object non nil -- does <%= f.name %> output what you expect?

Comment: If the f object exists for the f.name display, then there is an f.updated_at object as well.  All I have are some ideas: (1) look at what's in the f.updated_at value at loop at run time? (2) If you call to_formatted_s() with a null updated_at value does it error out or exit gracefully? (3) In your database, is updated_at defaulted to a NULL.  My schemas for time field look like this "t.datetime "updated_at", null: false"